# Does QT have a filter builder like this

Tags: c++, qt

I am curious if QT has some kind of a filter or condition builder like [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Filtering/FilterBuilder.aspx) . In the link try clicking on the yellow text with the checkbox under the table that says [Quantity] Is greater than '100' and the i need something like the box that pops up.

Comment: I have done that in a form. Where I added where clauses to the SQL that I used for the QSqlQueryModel.

Answer (score 2):

For filter, never did that myself, but after a quick search, you might want to use something like [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

Creating a popup windows with Qt can be quickly done with [QDialog](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qdialog.html) class